# The element which has v-show="false" attribution in prerendered page flickerings when opening the page

Tags: vue.js, prerender

It only occurs when I use prerender-spa-plugin to prerender a page. It invokes an element(a modal) which has `v-show="false"` attribution as default. But this modal always flickering when open the page even `v-show` never been true.
I already has `v-cloak` in this element.
What's the correct way in Vue style to avoid flickering?

Comment: Try v-if then. That should have it default to not render.

Comment: To complete @MartinXia, v_show build the dom element which invoke the page update, then set display attribute to none. The v-if condition (if false) do not build at all the element.

Comment: @Arc v-if goes to the same result, actually that's my option before v-show.

Comment: It only occurs when I prerender a page

Comment: Any luck with a solution here?  I'm running into issues as well...

Comment: @CamHart - found a solution? Running into the same.

Comment: @SaadmanIslamKhan I honestly don't remember.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "v-if" instead of "v-show" or "v-cloak"

Comment: v-if goes to the same result, actually that's my option before v-show.It only occurs when I prerender a page